# Need to execute a script prior to running Rails specs on a gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubymine

I have a gem that relies on the database of another rails application.

In order to run the gem locally, I set up a symlink in the gem's test/dummy/db to the schema.rb in the application.  Works great.

Recently there were some changes to the application's schema.rb to add lines like:

`create_function :current_master_org_id`

The gem complains when running the specs that it doesn't know what *create_function* is.

The gem doesn't need to know anything about the functions, I could run a script like:

```
sed -e '/create_view/{N;N;d;}' test/dummy/db/schema_original.rb | sed -e '/create_function/{N;d;}' > test/dummy/db/schema.rb
```

I'm wondering what a good solution to this problem could be?  Could I add a Rubymine "action" or something to scrub the schema.rb file prior to running specs?  What if someone wanted to run specs and didn't use Rubymine?

Any suggestions on how to get around this?

Comment: It is not clear what it is you're trying to test. But, it seems like you would want to remove the dependency by, perhaps, stubbing or some such thing. I mean, isn't the point to isolate the thing you're testing? Just a thought.

Comment: @jvillian, Sorry, this is for the component tests (specs) that need a test db to work from.  The specs actually work fine and pass so this isn't a super serious issue, but I would like to get rid of the big warning when running the tests.